# How to call uWebSockets http routes from front-end with axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, axios, uwebsockets

I'm using uWebSockets on my nodejs app and I'm trying to send some http requests to the wss server.
I can see the output of the GET routes on the wss server by accessing them from browser url bar, but when I try to call the PUT , POST , PATCH , ... routes I get no output ( e.g : no response, I think routes aren't reached ).

My uWebSockets.js configuration is the following code snippet :

```
const uWS = require('uWebSockets.js');
const SOCKET_PORT = 3023;

const websockets = uWS.App()

/* I tried to put these routes before and after .ws() , still no response */
.put('/route1', (req, res) => {
     console.log('/route1');
})
.patch('/route2', (req, res) => {
     console.log('/route2');
 })
.post('/route3', (req, res) => {
     console.log('/route3');
})
.delete('/route4', (req, res) => {
     console.log('/route4');
})

/* Tried with '' , '*' , '/*' but none of the attempts succeeed */
.ws('', {
     compression: uWS.SHARED_COMPRESSOR,
     idleTimeout: 30,
     maxBackpressure: 1024,
     maxPayloadLength: 512,
     open:ws=> ws.subscribe('all')
});


websockets.listen(SOCKET_PORT, (listenSocket) => {
    if (listenSocket) 
        console.log('Listening to port ' + SOCKET_PORT);
});
```

And from the front-end, I try to send the request like this :

```
    let header = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*" , "Content-Type" : "application/json" };
    header.key= "test_key";
    await axios({
        method : "PUT",
        url : "wss://subdomain.domain.xyz/route1",
        data : { "val1" : "test" , "val2" : 5 },
        headers : header
    })
    .then(function(response){
        serverResponse = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        serverResponse = err.response.data;
    });
```

Am I doing the websockets request wrong?

I'm using the 18.04 uWebSockets.js version.

Comment: You are trying to use HTTP client library to connect with websockets, axios for which it was not designed. If you insist on using websockets protocol you'd have to use some other library and change your logic

Comment: Indeed, I tried to use axios to call the websocket http routes. How exactly to change my logic and what other library to use?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using http/https not ws/wss to connect when using HTTP methods like GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, etc.

Comment: +1 Also, uWebsockets.js is both an HTTP and WebSockets server, so it shouldn't be an issue to access these routes using simple HTTP protocol.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've figured out in the meantime this is part of the problem. But still, accessing the routes via HTTP was working for GET routes only, the others were unreachable for some reason...